# Python Network Threading

Tags: python, multithreading

Okay i want to program a server with python.
Therefore i opened a socket and wait for the input.
When i get an input i get an further socket and and address.

Because I want to implement multiple connections at the same time I looked into multi-threading in python.

I create a thread the following way:

```
t = Thread(target=input, args=(conn, address, ))
t.start()
```

My input method looks the following:

```
def input(conn, address): [...]
```

Now if in this way I get the following stacktrace:

> Exception in thread Thread-1:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
>       self.run()
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
>       self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
>
> TypeError: input expected at most 1 argument, got 2

If i remove the address (and just give the conn) it prints the following:

```
<socket.socket fd=4, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('10.0.0.9', 3306), raddr=('10.0.0.9', 32908)>
```

How should I understand that?

Solution to the problem:
I need to call the method via self.input not input.

Comment: Using `input` as a function name isn't good practice - `input` is actually one of Python's built-in commands. ;-)  https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input

Comment: If you're going to use threading, be careful to use `threading.Lock` objects to protect writes to variables or other objects that could be accessed by more than one thread at a time. You can use the `with` statement with these locks. `with self._list_lock: self._my_list.append(v)` for instance. You can protect blocks of code this way without having to explicitly unlock (the with statement does that for you).

Comment: Some developers seem to like taking an event driven approach to network programming instead of using threading. twisted is the popular framework: https://www.twistedmatrix.com/trac/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

input is a [build-in python function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) which gets one argument so when you are trying to use input inside threading python supposed you want to use the built-in input function. change the function name will fix the issue:

```
def _input(conn, address): [...]


t = Thread(target=_input, args=(conn, address, ))
t.start()
```

PS: this way is not a good way to handle multithread networking

Comment: Thanks for the advice! i should have called the method with self.input^^ and what would be a better way multithread network traffic?